# Does ArcGIS 10 have a Geoprocessor Programming Model by using Arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, geoprocessing, arcpy

Does ArcGIS 10 have a Geoprocessor Programming Model by using Arcpy? 
is it possible to use ArcGIS 9.3 Geoprocessor Programming Model within ArcGIS 10?

Answer (score 5):

There is no version 10 Geoprocessor Programming Model.  Some of 9.3's is applicable, but your best source is the online help for [ArcPy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000v7000000.htm) and you will have to do a lot of scrolling and searching within there.  The fundamental are similar, but the help documentation plus some examples on the [Geoprocessing site](http://resources.esri.com/geoprocessing/) are your best sources for now.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you call by "Geoprocessor Programming Model".
If it means "PDF file with nice pictures officially provided by ESRI" then there is a NIMxxxxx about it and you know it will take some time.

Here is another way using [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html):

```
C:\Dev\arc-py>set PATH=C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib;%PATH%

C:\Dev\arc-py>pydoc.py -w "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Server10.0\arcpy"
wrote _importable_modules.html
wrote arceditor.html
wrote arcengine.html
wrote arcenginegeodb.html
wrote arcinfo.html
wrote arcpy.html
wrote arcpy._base.html
wrote arcpy._ga.html
wrote arcpy._graph.html
wrote arcpy._importable_modules.html
wrote arcpy._management.html
wrote arcpy._mapping.html
wrote arcpy.analysis.html
wrote arcpy.arc.html
wrote arcpy.arcobjects.html
no Python documentation found for 'arcpy.arcobjects._base'
no Python documentation found for 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion'
no Python documentation found for 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects'
no Python documentation found for 'arcpy.arcobjects.geometries'
wrote arcpy.arcobjects.mixins.html
wrote arcpy.ba.html
wrote arcpy.cartography.html
wrote arcpy.conversion.html
wrote arcpy.ddd.html
wrote arcpy.edit.html
wrote arcpy.fabric.html
wrote arcpy.ga.html
wrote arcpy.geocoding.html
wrote arcpy.geoprocessing.html
wrote arcpy.geoprocessing._base.html
wrote arcpy.interop.html
wrote arcpy.lr.html
wrote arcpy.management.html
wrote arcpy.mapping.html
wrote arcpy.md.html
wrote arcpy.na.html
wrote arcpy.sa.html
wrote arcpy.sa.CompoundParameter.html
wrote arcpy.sa.Functions.html
wrote arcpy.sa.ParameterClasses.html
wrote arcpy.sa.Utils.html
wrote arcpy.schematics.html
wrote arcpy.server.html
wrote arcpy.stats.html
wrote arcpy.ta.html
wrote arcpy.toolbox.html
wrote arcpy.toolbox_code.html
wrote arcpy.utils.html
wrote arcserver.html
wrote arcview.html

C:\Dev\arc-py>start arcpy.html
```

PS. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199739/pydoc-fails-u
nder-windows-and-python-2-6-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199739/pydoc-fails-under-windows-and-python-2-6-4) why PATH-hack is needed.

Comment: Is this run at the command line or in IDLE?

Comment: This is command line (CMD). pydoc has issues in Python 2.6 (packaged with AGS10) on Windows, therefore here is PATH-hack at beginning. But you can try.

Comment: -1. I hardly see how this is any better than the official documentation included in the help. In fact, the documentation strings you see in the pydoc are taken directly _from_ the help system.

Comment: @Justin, David Wynne showed how to this in IDLE, [link](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/10395-Geoprocessing-modules-tools-functions-reference-listing)

Answer (score 1):

I found this while doing a search for the same thing:

http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008EIeAAM

"An unofficial arcPy OMD has just been posted on the ArcGIS Forums.  Just for a nice poster to hang on your wall.

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/50806-ArcPy-Geoprocessor-OMD-v10-Unofficial"

Comment: BTW - I havent looked to check the accuracy of it yet. So I dont know if its any good.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF for version 10 is available here: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fe43556c8fd94ddc9af5a07f4d515fbd

Comment: This doesn't truly answer the question. Link only answers tend to go stale, so its better to provide at least some context.