# What parts of ArcGIS 9.3 Geoprocessor Programming Model diagram are not relevant for ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing

The [geoprocessor programming model](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/pdf/Geoprocessor_93.pdf) was an excellent tool for python scripting using ArcGIS 9.3. There is still no equivalent diagram for ArcGIS 10 - although there [is a request on the ArcGIS ideas site](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008EIe&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=ArcGIS%2bDesktop).

[Does ArcGIS 10 have a Geoprocessor Programming Model by using Arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9879/geoprocessor-programming-model) asked if the 9.3 diagram is good to use for ArcGIS 10. The answer was that some of it is relevant and it is best not to use it. However, I really like the diagram and would like to reference it when scripting ArcGIS 10. Therefore my specific question is:

What parts of the ArcGIS 9.3 diagram are not relevant to ArcGIS 10? Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand, if an equivalent diagram was made for ArcGIS 10, there would be new functions added to the diagram; the diagram would only get bigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main differences between arcgisscripting and arcpy, are instantiation and a more rigid adherence to a naming convention, i.e. [tool_name]_[category](*args, **kwargs)

Apart from that the [answer from Dan Patterson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17080/115) is correct, you'll have to look at each tool to determine if the functionality or parameters have changed for each tool.

ArcPy is an elaborate stub for COM objects.  Using a COM library from python has the added overhead of translating python data types to c/c++ data types.  And often requires some complex conversions.  Being aware of this, and having an understanding of COM will help you squeeze performance out of your scripts where necessary.